# How to make the child follow the parent's rotation in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a top-down game with a camera looking flat to the ground (which means it's tilted 90 degrees downwards). I am making a turret rotation that follows the location of the mouse.

I have successfully made it look at the mouse in a flat manner but whenever I go to ramps, it doesn't rotate as the parent as you can see on the screenshots.

[Ship Orientation on ramp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USAyz.png)

[Zoomed view to turret](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwR8J.png)

I have a script on an Empty Game Object which is the parent of the cannon. I currently have this line of codes in the Update() function

```
Vector3 v3T = Input.mousePosition;
v3T.z = Mathf.Abs (Camera.main.transform.position.y - transform.position.y);
v3T = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (v3T);
transform.LookAt (v3T);
```

How do I make the Empty Game Object to follow the parent's (I'm referring to the ship) rotation?

Comment: Is the turret a child of your ship?

Comment: @ZayedUpal Yes, and there's an empty game object which holds the cannon as the child. On that the same empty game object also where these code are located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rotate the canon only on y axis. Like this:

```
transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0,transform.localEulerAngles.y,0);
```

Add the above code after your LookAt function. You can replace the 0's above with the starting x and y euler angles of the turret.

Comment: Amazing! That worked but you need to structure it this way.

`transform.LookAt (v3T);
transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0,transform.localEulerAngles.y,0);`

I am new to Euler Angles but thanks anyway!